# How to automatically generate the site map path in page header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitemap, sitemappath

I used web.sitemap to generate the site map path for my asp.net application.
and I can generate two lays just like:
http://localhost:8080/test.aspx
but If i need to generate the MVC path like this:
http://localhost:8080/test.aspx/edit/2
and I need to know the "2" to get the site map.
Is there any method that I can use wild card
http://localhost:8080/test.aspx/edit/*
and then for this kind of path, system will auto generate the path at the page header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's not possible. The default provider of Sitemap is static. You've to write a dynamic sitemap provider to generate the sitemap nodes from the data source.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamicsitemap.aspx